# How to use gnuplot commands inside a shell script?

Tags: command-line, scripts, gnuplot

I have this shell script :

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

gnuplot -e "set terminal png; set output "out.png"; set boxwidth 0.5; set style fill solid; plot "ax.txt" using 1:2:xtic(3) with boxes"
```

Where I try to generate a bar chart with a txt file, but I get the following error:

```
line 0: internal error : STRING operator applied to undefined or non-STRING variable
```

the content of my ax.txt is:

```
 1       40 CATS
 2       35 DOGS
 3       30 FISH
 4       25 BIRD
 5       20 BLABLA
 6       15 TURTLES
 7       10 SNAKES
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest quotes like that - either use different quotes for the shell and for gnuplot:

```
gnuplot -e "set terminal png; set output 'out.png'; set boxwidth 0.5; set style fill solid; plot 'ax.txt' using 1:2:xtic(3) with boxes"
```

or

```
gnuplot -e 'set terminal png; set output "out.png"; set boxwidth 0.5; set style fill solid; plot "ax.txt" using 1:2:xtic(3) with boxes'
```

or escape the inner quotes:

```
gnuplot -e "set terminal png; set output \"out.png\"; set boxwidth 0.5; set style fill solid; plot \"ax.txt\" using 1:2:xtic(3) with boxes"
```

or take a different approach altogether and use a *here document* to pass commands via stdin rather than as a `-e` command string:

```
$ gnuplot <<EOF
set terminal png
set output "out.png"
set boxwidth 0.5; set style fill solid
plot "ax.txt" using 1:2:xtic(3) with boxes
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are reinventing gnuplot scripts. You *could* use a "here document", but I'd recommend you do it the way it is intended to use: With a separate script for your gnuplot commands. Simply invoke it with `gnuplot myscript`.

See also

http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_5.0/

If you do it from a shell script, you need to know exactly what quotes the shell "eats" and how you need to escape quotes that you really need for your gnuplot script. Do yourself the favour and keep it simple: Put the gnuplot parts into a separate script. You can even add the `gnuplot` command as a *she-bang* that tells the system what interpreter you want that script invoked with. Just add a first line with this comment:

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
```

and make the script executable, of course (`chmod 755 myscript`).